# Codeigniter MySQL query to array

Tags: mysql, arrays, codeigniter

I have the following CI Query builder query

```
$query_teams = $this->db->get_where('teams_in_cups', array('cup_id' => 2));
$team_ids=$query_teams->result_array();
```

I want `$team_ids` (which currently outputs two ids->22 and 25) to be compatible with the following query

```
$this->db->where_in('id', $team_ids);    
$query_team_details = $this->db->get('teams');
```

In the second query, $team_ids should look like the following
array(22,25);

I tried foreach, implode, explode, no how managed to get it to work.

Any help is highly appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use MySQL join to get the desired result.

I am fixing your current situation only.

```
$query_teams = $this->db->get_where('teams_in_cups', array('cup_id' => 2));
$team_data=$query_teams->result();
team_ids='';
foreach($team_data as $td)
{
   $team_ids=$team_id.','.$td->team_id;
}
$team_ids=ltrim($team_ids,',');
$this->db->where_in('id', $team_ids);    
$query_team_details = $this->db->get('teams');
```

Comment: Thanks for fast answer,but '$td->team_id' returns undefined variable error. In MySQL the column name is team_id so I don't know why could it be?

Comment: use your own database table column name in place of `team_id`. I have just given one example.

Comment: inside the foreach, what does the variable $team_id do? Because it is not defined anywhere.

Comment: This is an imaginary item, I added, as you have not given the table structure. update the code as per the table structure or update the question with table structure, I will update the solution.